# how to pass button intent to make drawable change color in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and Java and have been working on a project for some time now and would appreciate help with an issue I cannot seem to find any tutorials or information on.
I am using android **Studio version 3.1.4** on a computer running **Windows 7 pro**.

I cannot fit all my buttons and all my drawables onto the `MainActivity`, so I want all my buttons on the `MainActivity` and all my drawables on Activity 2.

My Problem is that I cannot work out how to make my drawables change color in the second Activity when I click any buttons in the `MainActivity`.

My drawables in the form of circles are in svg format with a diameter of 10mm
I have pasted all relevant code for 3 buttons to work with 3 svg drawable on the `MainActivity` so that you can see how it works on a virtual device or your mobile connected via a usb cable.
I have also added a button in the main activity to take you to Activity 2 where I have put 3 drawable that I need to work in the same way as the main activity but with the buttons from the first activity changing them.
In my project I have many buttons. Each button when clicked changes the color of its related SVG drawable as per my program.  The drawable are black to start with. Each click will make them change to the next colors in this sequential order. White, Yellow, Orange, Red, then back to black

So what I need to do is have my buttons in the main activity and the drawables in activity 2.
If Button 1 (attribute is btn1) is clicked in a`ctivity_main.xml` I want the button information passed to `Activity2` to make the drawable with attribute `iv1` change color.

So if you were to click `Button1`, `Button2`, `Button3`, `Button4` and use the go to `activity2` button (attribute btn) the drawable in `Activity2` would be white, yellow, white from left to right.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<package com.example.chucky.svg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    int[] colors = {0xffffffff, 0xffffff00, 0xffff6600, 0xffff0000, 0xff000000};
    int counter1 = -1;
    int counter2 = -1;
    int counter3 = -1;

    ImageView iv1;
    ImageView iv2;
    ImageView iv3;

    Button btn;
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });


        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter3++;
                if (counter3> colors.length -1){
                    counter3 = 0;
                }
                iv3.setColorFilter(colors[counter3]);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter2++;
                if (counter2> colors.length - 1){
                    counter2 = 0;
                }
                iv2.setColorFilter(colors[counter2]);
            }
        });


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter1++;
                if (counter1> colors.length - 1){
                    counter1 = 0;
                }
                iv1.setColorFilter(colors[counter1]);
            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

`Activity2` class

```
package com.example.chucky.svg;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }
    }
```

`Activity_main` xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text=" Button 1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.091"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button 2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button 3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.895"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Go to Activity 2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.137"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.852"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_2` xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity2">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.852"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.137"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_e" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Activity2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Main Activity]

[image: Activity 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have colour codes in integer array `int[] colors` and selected position in `counter` variable. By the way set color to imageview | pass it via intent.

Try below code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("COLOR_1",colors[counter1]);
    i.putExtra("COLOR_2",colors[counter2]);
    i.putExtra("COLOR_3",colors[counter3]);
    startActivity(i);
```

Then in `Activity2` get intent value & set to corresponding `ImageView`.

Add this code in `onCreate()`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        iv1.setColorFilter(bundle.getInt("COLOR_1",0));
        iv2.setColorFilter(bundle.getInt("COLOR_2",0));
        iv3.setColorFilter(bundle.getInt("COLOR_3",0));
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your options and have managed partial success. I will correct errors and post my result. Please be patient I am rather busy for a while.

Comment: This option worked. Thank you. I had problems with my counters and it crashed when opening without a color. I have amended it and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to pass an information to the second activity, extract, and make use of the information.

With an Intent Extra your goal can be achievable just like this:

First of all, declare a unique constant variable in your second activity that will hold information across the communication.

```
public static final String EXTRA_USER_ID = "userId";
```

Now, `FirstActivity` sending info:

```
 String changeColorToBlack = " black"
 Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivty.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_COLOR_KEY, changeColorToBlack);
                startActivity(intent);
```

`SecondActivity` can retrieve the information like this

```
 String colorIdKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_COLOR_ID);
        if (colorIdKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_COLOR_KEY");
        }
//colorIdKey is your color
```

That is all. All you need is an Intent Extra to pass information between 2 activities

Comment: Im not sure what does "//colorIdkey is your color" mean

Comment: Is just a sample data. In that way, you can tell other activity to change color to black, since is black button you pressed. Then use ` if else` statement to check if is black button that was clicked to apply black color

Comment: I have added both activity screen captures from my Mobile of the Project I am trying to work on

Comment: I'm on mobile now. But i will try do something.

Comment: Now you have your buttons. For each of the buttons add the intents in my code to the onClick.

Comment: Get the color code as value to string `changeColorToBlack` for black do for others too.

Comment: Try the answer. Is very straight forward.

Comment: I am so new to Java and android, I cannot make new code. I have tried to make your idea work, but I get errors trying to send code to my mobile

Comment: Ok. When am back on system. I will help you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to active what you required is pass the color codes to second activity as arguments

in Activity1.class do this

> public void openActivity2() {
>
> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
> ```
>
> // pass the color value as bundle
>
> ```
> intent.putExtra("color1", <color_code1>);  
> intent.putExtra("color2", <color_code2>);
> intent.putExtra("color3", <color_code3>);
>
> startActivity(intent); }
> ```

in Activity2.class

> ```
> public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
>     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
>
>     if(extras != null){
>
>     String color1 = extras.getString("color1");
>     String color2 = extras.getString("color2");
>     String color3 = extras.getString("color3");
>
>     // set values to image views here
>      }
>    }
> }
> ```

Official documentation here  : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#kotlin